# Function/Stored Procedure for insert between two tables based on condition

Tags: sql-server, function

I'm already sorry ... I am quite new to this whole posting stuff, but I am trying my best ...

I got two tables ... 'Customer' and 'Rooms' ... a single Customer with a UNIQUE CU_ID is staying in a room (with a UNIQUE ROOM_ID, unfortunately for me, sometimes there are 2 or three CU_ID staying in the same Room ... they usually check in at the same day though, so the CheckInDate should be the same ...

When they check in and the RoomNo is entered on the 'Customer'-Table I would like the Bit-Field 'Occupied' in the 'Rooms'-Table to be set to "TRUE". That part I got done with a Trigger (see below) ...

The trick is when they are checking out ... If a User manually marks the "Occupied"-(Bit)Field for that Room-ID as "FALSE", then I would like to set the DepartDate on the Customer-Table for ANY Customer staying in that room at the MOMENT to Getdate().

Here's my tables, Trigger, and some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms](
[Room_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Room_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Occupied] [bit] NULL,
    [CheckInDate] [int] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Rooms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Room_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
[CU_ID] [int] IDENTITY(5000,1) NOT NULL,
[CheckInDate] [datetime] NULL,
[RoomNo] [int] NOT NULL,
[Nights_Booked] [int] NULL,
[DepartDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CU_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Rooms] FOREIGN KEY([RoomNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Rooms] ([Room_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Rooms]
GO

-- 2 Tables created including PK/FK Relationship
```

Here's my Trigger for the first step ... updating the bit column Occupied to True when Room_ID is used for new Check-In:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[Occupied] 
ON [dbo].[Customer]
FOR INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
RETURN
UPDATE Rooms
SET [Occupied] = 'True'
FROM  Rooms r
JOIN Customer cu
ON cu.[RoomNo] = r.[Room_ID]
Join INSERTED INS
ON cu.[RoomNo] = INS.[RoomNo]
END
GO
```

I enter some test data into both of them ...

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Rooms ON

INSERT INTO Rooms
(Room_ID, Room_No, Occupied) 
SELECT 1, 'A14', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B2', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C3', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D8', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'K9', 0 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Rooms OFF

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customer ON

INSERT INTO Customer
(CU_ID, CheckInDate, RoomNo, Nights_Booked, DepartDate) 
SELECT 5000, '2013-05-10', 1, 4, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5001, '2013-05-10', 1, 4, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5002, '2013-05-10', 2, 2, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5003, '2013-05-10', 3, 3, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5004, '2013-05-11', 4, 4, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5005, '2013-05-11', 4, 4, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5006, '2013-05-11', 4, 4, NULL

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customer OFF

-- Test Data entered in rows on 'Rooms' and 'Customer'-Tables
```

The Trigger works fine and it updates all the Records with the same Room_ID (RoomNo respectively on Customer Table).

I tried to solve my problem with other Triggers. And I get SQL Server to enter the Depart-Date based on the Check-In-Date of the specific Customer, if I pass that one on to the Room-Table. Unfortunately it only updates the Data with the 1st Entry made for that specific Room_ID on the Rooms-Table ... and it seems awkwardly much passing back and forth between the two tables. I guess I need a Stored Procedure/Function to actually accomplish that:

- On Insert of Customer Record pass NEWEST CheckInDate and Insert into Room-Table Field CheckInDate
- When Rooms.Occupied is marked as 'False', set the Check-Out-Date for all CU_ID with Customer.RoomNo = Rooms.Room_ID AND Customer.CheckInDate = Rooms.CheckInDate to GETDATE() ...

I struggle with the first part - how to pass the CheckInDate on Insert and if a value is existing update it with the newer date ...

No idea, again ... I'm all new :)

Thanks for any help in advance !!!

Comment: Triggers are an unmaintainable mess.  Write a front end that updates both the user and the room table with separate queries.  (Nice question anway, I've voted for it, maybe someone without trigger phobia will answer it :))

Comment: Cheers for the reply :) The front end is not an option (3rd Party) - Triggers are a mess - the simple one in this case just changing a Bit-Field to True on Insert is rather maintainable though - that's why I was looking more for ideas for Stored Procedure / Function to get what I want - any ideas appreciated - thanks for the Vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, it would be very helpful to us if you keep the examples short. In this case, for example, all we would have needed is a few columns from each table (none of the options/constraints).

You shouldn't be manually updating bits. Use stored procedures instead.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CheckoutRoom] (
    @RoomID
)
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[Rooms]
    SET [Occupied] = 0
    WHERE [Room_ID] = @RoomID

    UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]
    SET [DepartDate] = GETDATE()
    WHERE [RoomNo] = @RoomID
END
```

I'm assuming you're still working on the design of your system, but what happens if a single customer checks out multiple rooms? You need a Customer/Room cross reference table.

```
[dbo].[Customer]
[dbo].[Room]
[dbo].[CustomerRoom]
```

Also note that it isn't obvious that [dbo].[Customer].[RoomNo] is actually the [RoomID].

Comment: Hi J Lo, 
sorry for the long Post, I'll keep it shorter in the future, just got told to put as much info in it as possible ... as I said, this whole posting is new for me :)
Updating the Bit-Field is done by the End-User via .asp-Application, so that one is fix. We had three tables, but our business logic works different, so the [CustomerRoom] is unnecessary, as Customer gets Room assigned, so it's not like a Hotel Reservation ... Thanks already anyways